# Swift 3 - Pulling images from mySQL database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, json, swift

I am currently in the process of designing an application that has a newsfeed. Images and text are stored in our database but I am having trouble pulling the image and displaying it. The code I have should work but I am getting a fatal error saying "THREAD 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" around

```
let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
```

and the compiler displays this message - "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

I'm getting the error in this snippet of code:

```
if!path!.isEmpty {
    let url = URL(string: path!)!
    let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
    self.images.append(image)
} else {
    let image = UIImage()
    self.images.append(image)
}
```

Being very new to programming, I've been stuck on this for quite a while now. If there is anything you suggest, let me know! Thanks!

Also, the photo I am trying to retrieve is a .jpg, not sure if that may be important.

(Here's the rest of the code if it is needed)

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var activities = [AnyObject]()
var images = [UIImage]()

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 0, 0, 0)


}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return activities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "activity", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    let post = activities[indexPath.row]
    let image = images[indexPath.row]
    let username = post["username"] as? String
    let text = post["text"] as? String

    cell.titleLbl.text = text
    cell.userLbl.text = username
    cell.activityImage.image! = image
    //cell.dateLbl.text = activities[indexPath.row]
    //cell.activityImage.image = images[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    loadActivities()
}


func loadActivities() {
    let id = user!["id"] as! String
    let url = URL(string: "https://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team7/posts.php")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let body = "id=\(id)&text=&uuid="
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            if error == nil {

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    // clean up
                    self.activities.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.images.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    guard let parseJSON = json else {
                        print("Error while parsing")
                        return
                    }

                    guard let posts = parseJSON["posts"] as? [AnyObject] else {
                        print("Error while parseJSONing")
                        return
                    }


                    self.activities = posts

                    for i in 0 ..< self.activities.count {

                        let path = self.activities[i]["path"] as? String

                        if !path!.isEmpty {
                            let url = URL(string: path!)!
                            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
                            self.images.append(image)
                        } else {
                            let image = UIImage()
                            self.images.append(image)
                        }

                    }



                    self.tableView.reloadData()


                } catch {
                }

            } else {
            }

        })

        }.resume()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}

extension NSMutableData {

func appendString(_ string : String) {

    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
    append(data!)

}

}
```

Comment: Do not force unwrap with !. Use if let construct to unwrap optionals. E.g. 'if let actualObject = optionalProperty { ... }'

Comment: Path or imagedata is nil and you are force unwrapping it hence the error

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: I tried this before but with my lack of general programming knowledge I'm not sure if I was doing it right. So would it be if let imageData = image { let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!}?

Comment: please see my answer and try that

Comment: could you please accept my answer as correct if it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing all of this ? Get the URLs of the images from your server and then load them asynchronously in cellForRowAtIndexPath using SDWebImage. It is a library you can find it here. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage. This way you won't need to store your images in an array and it will be faster to load.

Or you can also implement your own async loading of images.

Comment: It's for my capstone project, we have to use a mySQL database and php to retrieve it. Thanks for your help though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes this is the way the do it using mySQL and PHP

Comment: Oh, well honestly, like I said, I'm very new to programming and all that doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: The way you are loading the images is one by one. It takes too much time. If you change this, you won't need to use the Data thing. It will all work

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this to avoid runtime errors:

```
if let actualPath = path, !actualPath.isEmpty, let url = URL(string: actualPath) {
    if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            self.images.append(image)
        }
    }
}
```

instead of this

```
if!path!.isEmpty {
    let url = URL(string: path!)!
    let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
    self.images.append(image)
}
```